# Filepicker in WP8.1 app did not show any photo

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, gallery, filepicker

I need to make instrument, that allows users to choose photo from Gallery. After choosing photo, it will be shown to the user in ImageBox.

Problem is, that when user chooses some photo in Gallery, Gallery closes, ImageBox stays empty. Code returns no error. Please help me to find error and solve this problem. Thank you.

Here is a code:

```
ImagePath = String.Empty

    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
        filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
        ' Filter to include a sample subset of file types
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear()
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp")
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png")
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg")
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg")
        filePicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue()


        Dim BitmapImage = New BitmapImage()
        Await BitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(filePicker)
        MyPhoto.Source = BitmapImage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `filePicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue()` you need to add code into the `App_Activated`

You will notice that `PickSingleFileAndContinue()` is a void method will not return the picked file were as `PickSingleFileAsync()` will return a file.

Code block is in `C#`,sorry i have only limited knowledge in `vb`, you can find vb sample below

[Similar SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25764290/1876572)

**C#**

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

As your are using `PickSingleFileAndContinue()` you need to implement `ContinuationManager` that were you get the file you picked.

In the App.xaml.cs

```
public ContinuationManager ContinuationManager { get; private set; }
```

*This will fire when the app get activated*

```
    protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);

        continuationManager = new ContinuationManager();

        Frame rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();
        await RestoreStatusAsync(e.PreviousExecutionState);

        if(rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }

        var continuationEventArgs = e as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
        if (continuationEventArgs != null)
        {
            Frame scenarioFrame = MainPage.Current.FindName("ScenarioFrame") as Frame;
            if (scenarioFrame != null)
            {
                // Call ContinuationManager to handle continuation activation
                continuationManager.Continue(continuationEventArgs, scenarioFrame);
            }
        }

        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

**Usage in the page**

Assume that one page of your app contains code that calls a FileOpenPicker to pick an existing file. In this class, implement the corresponding interface from the ContinuationManager helper class. When your app uses a FileOpenPicker, the interface to implement is IFileOpenPickerContinuable.

```
 public sealed partial class Scenario1 : Page, IFileOpenPickerContinuable
{
    ...

//inside this you have this

private void PickAFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        // Launch file open picker and caller app is suspended
        // and may be terminated if required
        openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
    }
}


switch (args.Kind)
    {
        case ActivationKind.PickFileContinuation:
            var fileOpenPickerPage = rootFrame.Content as IFileOpenPickerContinuable;
            if (fileOpenPickerPage != null)
            {
                fileOpenPickerPage.ContinueFileOpenPicker(args as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs);
            }
            break;

        ...
    }
```

[Download msdn sample here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba)

[Msdn documentation using FilePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn614994)

Comment: Thank you very much for complete answer