# XAML c# pick maxiumum 4 images from library with filepicker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm just wondering if there is a default user interface to pick one or more photos within in a Windows Phone 8.1 application?

In a chat window I want to display two buttons (pick a file & capture a photo) and before I start want to know if I have to do the file picker with thumbnails, folder etc by myself or does the WinRT Api provide something by default?

The same question got asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719797/file-picker-in-windows-phone-8-1), but I also would like to know if there is a way to limit this filePicker to 4 images or would I have to implement this by own?

Thank You

Comment: You can use FileOpenPicker in Windows Phone 8.1 to choose picture from Picture Gallery. for example refer answer of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719797/file-picker-in-windows-phone-8-1

Comment: Seems great. Will have a look at it. Thx

Comment: Great links. Thank You. 
The post from @isscroberto in that thread works pretty perfekt. I'll changed it slighly and made it work for a multiple file picker with that line: `filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();` 
Last question: Is there a way to limit this filePicker to 4 images or would I have to implement this by own?

Comment: you can ask separate question regarding limiting the files  as this question is closed.